# PHP:How To Initialize Variable?

Tags: php, variables

I have one question to you, and I hope you will help me. I want to write calculator but i don't have chance tu change operations , I can only use addition operation. I don't know what happened. can anyone help me?

look at it, what happened?

```
<?php
$x = isset($_POST['field']);
if($x == 1){ 
    echo $x + 5;
}
elseif($x == 2){
    echo $x - 5;
}
?>
```

Comment: 1. `var_dump($x);` 2. http://php.net/isset

Comment: `isset` always returns boolean so `$x` will either be `true` or `false`. So comparing it with `2` does not make any sense. BTW, your question does not make sense as well.

Comment: @Jon `$x == 2 can never be true because no boolean compares equal to 2` No. 2 evaluates to `true` so `2 == true => true`. :)

Comment: Calculator with PHP. bad idea.

Comment: @PLB: You are so right. And this, folks, is why we never compare values to `true` or `false` unless the comparison is done with `===`. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You code is wrong as this line will evaluate only as 0 (false) or 1 (true) if condition is met:

```
$x = isset($_POST['field']);
```

You need to do it that way:

```
$x = isset($_POST['field']) ? $_POST['field'] : 0;
```

(where 0 is default value, `$x` is assigned to in case there's no `$_POST['field`]` set.

Answer (score 0):

```
$x = isset($_POST['field']) ? (int)$_POST['field'] : 0;
```

You want the value, not the boolean if it's set or not.

Comment: Oh yeah, didn't notice he's doing math with it. Updated the answer.